# thread safe implementation gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I am using a thread safe Q to generate some random number inside the buffer. On the main glWidget program I should DeQ the buffer contents and update the screen.

```
#ifndef CONCURRENTQUEUE_H
#define CONCURRENTQUEUE_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QMutex>

class ConcurrentQueue
{
private:
    unsigned short segments[360][100];

public:
    ConcurrentQueue();
    void InitSegments();
    void Enqueue(int i, int j, unsigned short value);
    unsigned short Dequeue(int i, int j);

    bool isEmpty();
private:
    QMutex mutex;
};

#endif // CONCURRENTQUEUE_H

ConcurrentQueue::ConcurrentQueue()
{
    InitSegments();
}

void ConcurrentQueue::InitSegments()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        {
            segments[i][j] = 0;
        }
}

void ConcurrentQueue::Enqueue(int i, int j, unsigned short value)
{
    mutex.lock();
    segments[i][j] = value;
    mutex.unlock();
}
unsigned short ConcurrentQueue::Dequeue(int i, int j)
{
    unsigned short color = 0;
    mutex.lock();
    color = segments[i][j];
    mutex.unlock();

    return color;
}
```

GenerateBuffers Class:

```
#ifndef GENERATEBUFFERS_H
#define GENERATEBUFFERS_H

#include <QThread>   
#include "thread_safe/concurrentqueue.h"

class GenerateBuffers : public QThread
{
public:
    GenerateBuffers();

    void run();

    int rounds;
    int segmentIndex;    
};

#endif // GENERATEBUFFERS_H

#include "generatebuffers.h"    
#include <time.h>

ConcurrentQueue segmentsQueue;  
GenerateBuffers::GenerateBuffers()
{
    segmentIndex = 1;   
    run();
}

void GenerateBuffers::run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        int angleIndex = segmentIndex * 23;

        for(int i = angleIndex - 23; i < angleIndex; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                unsigned short randNumber = rand() % 255;

                segmentsQueue.Enqueue(i, j, randNumber);
            }

        if(segmentIndex > 16)
        {
            segmentIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        segmentIndex++;

        usleep(150);
    }
}
```

I created an instance of ConcurrentQ in generateBuffers .cpp file

```
ConcurrentQueue segmentsQueue;
```

and in the glWidget header file I declared:
extern ConcurrentQueue segmentsQueue;

and I used it this way:

```
    ppi->highlight(j, i, segmentsQueue.Dequeue(i, j));
```

the program terminates when I run it, I am not sure if my thread safe implementation is correct. could you tell me your opinion about the code please.

Comment: How to make it work? Make it right! What's your actual question? I can't image how you receive a definition.

Comment: how to define a the queue global to files, so that when generate buffers EnQs, glWidget.cpp could DeQ without getting multiple definition error.

Comment: let me guess, the multiple variable is `segmentsQueue` remove this at the end of the class declaration in the header file. the better way is in the header file: `extern ConcurrentQueue segmentsQueue;` and `ConcurrentQueue segmentsQueue;` in the cpp. but global variables are nasty, there are better solutions, like a singleton or a singleton pool.

Comment: could you take a look at the updated code please

Comment: You need to run your program under a debugger and figure out how it terminates and why. As a side note, it is misleading to name a "queue" something which is not a queue. You probably want to give your class a more apt name.

Comment: should have used `QMutexLocker`, made `ConcurrentQueue` a singleton, and should have not called `run()` in thread constructor, but the first place to check is probably the `segments[i][j]` where your index may be out of bounds

Comment: When `segmentIndex` reaches 16, the value of `angleIndex` becomes 368. This results in access past the end of the `ConcurrentQueue::segments` array.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to guess with the problem here i tried the most simple one: index bounds. So
In your run() method you're trying to bound segmentIndex to 16. Imagine

```
  segmentIndex == 16
```

And now inside the loop

```
  if(segmentIndex > 16)   // segmentIndex == 16, (16 > 16) is false
  {
    segmentIndex = 0;
  }
  else
  { // we go that way
    segmentIndex++;   // segmentIndex gets 17
  }
```

Now on the next loop run

```
  // segmentIndex is 17
  int angleIndex = segmentIndex * 23;   // 17 * 23 == 391

  for(int i = angleIndex - 23; i < angleIndex; i++)   // i = [368,391)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
    {
      unsigned short randNumber = rand() % 255;

      // unsigned short segments[360][100];
      segmentsQueue.Enqueue(i, j, randNumber);    
      // enqueue doesn't check index, causes crash
    }
  }
```

So your code is not going to work. Please don't use magic numbers in your code (360, 100, 23, 16) to avoid this kinds of problems.
By the way you could have simply debugged the problem.

Also, this code probably doesn't do what you think it does

```
GenerateBuffers::GenerateBuffers()
{
    segmentIndex = 1;   
    run();
}
```

run() gets called on the *same* thread. You probably wanted `start()` instead